# 'Flash for Android' vs 'AIR for Android' - differences?

Tags: android, flash, air

Froyo and Flash Player are coming to our phones.

In the Adobe PreRelease programs we can find AIR beta for Froyo and Eclair. With that, I can develop a Flash app and export it to my phone.

So, is AIR player the Flash player? o_O
I can't understand what differences are between AIR and Flash on Android.

Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Flash and AIR work just the same on Android as they do on the PC - similar technologies, but Flash plays in a browser and AIR apps are used like native applications. In other words, to use an AIR app, you'll typically install it from the Google Market, and put a shortcut to it on your homescreen, then launch it and use it like any other application. Whereas for flash content, you'll follow a link or a bookmark, and see the content embedded within a web page.

Anyway the capabilities of the two engines are similar (AIR does basically all that Flash does, and adds on some extra features suitable for applications), but the difference is in the way you access and use the content.

Comment: Could you refer any simple but good android flash tutorial on the web?

Comment: Flash is essentially the same on Android as it is on windows or linux or mac. Even for features like multitouch that depend on device capabilities, the actual APIs are the same everywhere. So any good tutorial is good for Android!